# how to revert back to branch commits

Tags: xcode

after clicking on the button, the switch to a certain commit xcode switched to from a branch to something else
Now it saves commits outside of any tags

How to go back to some branch and it is desirable to save the commit that I have already made[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLygY.png)